# How to send email with secureserver.net?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have a requirement to send an email,I have successfully sent email with below code to send email with gmail  `smtp.gmail.com:587` as smtp server.But i am getting error with `smtpout.asia.secureserver.net` my following code

```
import smtplib

def sendemail(to_addr_list='abcd.123@xxxxx.com', cc_addr_list='abcd.3214@xxxxxx.com',
          subject='Test mail', message='this is a test mail', from_addr='TestAddress',
          login='user123@xxxx.co', password='xxxxxxxx',
          smtpserver='smtpout.asia.secureserver.net:25'):
    header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
    header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
    header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
    header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
    message = header + message

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
    server.quit()
    return problems

sendemail()
```

I am getting the following error

`raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.`

How to solve this.?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sent email with godaddy secureserver with the below code

```
import smtplib

to = 'to address'
user = 'your_mail_id'#your secureserver mail_id(godaddy)
pwd = 'your_password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtpout.asia.secureserver.net",80)
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(user, pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + user + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
print header
msg = header + '\n Thank you for registring.\n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(user, to, msg)
print 'done!'
smtpserver.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self-explaining -- the specified server doesn't support explicit TLS (STARTTLS command) on given port. This can mean that you need to connect to other port (eg. 587) to have explicit TLS or that you need to connect to some other port (465) using implicit TLS mode. Check server documentation for details.

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question,I have successfully sent with gmail i am getting problem with secureserver.net

Comment: as @Eugene said, it's a question of ports, 587 works for gmail this is why you have succeeded this far but for TLS you need to ask your system administrator to dedicate a port for your smtp.

Comment: @toufikovich,Yes i have tried all the ports 80,25 etc,But i am not getting result.Actually main problem is i don't know how to work with `smtpout.asia.secureserver.net`

Comment: @Mulagala are you trying to send a mail through a website hosted on GoDaddy? it might be an SSL certificate issue, for example port 80 is secure...

Comment: @toufikovich,Thanks for information,If you know how to send with email as SSL please let me know..!

Comment: @Mulagala, just one more thing ... have you tried to add `server.ehlo()` before opening `server.starttls()` ? i'm trying to troubleshoot here but don't have your work environment :)

Comment: @Mulagala no worries my brother... please post your solution when you find it :)